# Why do sites still use <meta name="keywords">?

Tags: search-engine, meta-tags, meta

The keywords meta tag seems like a staggering dinosaur from the early days of failing to trick Google. Search engines naturally prioritize actually readable words, as users don't want information they can't see, right?

So why do Tumblr and Youtube automatically insert meta tags?

[A youtube watch page:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVD0vHZcYAk)

```
<meta name="keywords" content="sonic the hedgehog, final fantasy, mega man x, i swear i am not abusing tags, newgrounds, flash">
```

[Tumblr's official staff blog:](http://staff.tumblr.com/)

```
<meta name="keywords" content="features,HQ Update,Tumblr Tuesday,Esther Day" />
```

In both cases, the keywords are taken from the explicitly user-entered tags. Youtube takes them from any tags that the uploader specified, and Tumblr takes the first 5 post tags on the page. (Tumblr even automatically inserts these tags on every blog page without the ability to opt-out.)

There must be some reason they're going through this trouble, right? Are they for older/smaller search engines? Internal analytics? I can't imagine it's an enormous strain on their servers, but the existence shows they prioritize **something** highly enough for the small additional loads.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keywords meta tag: Useful or time waster?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300814/keywords-meta-tag-useful-or-time-waster) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103202/why-do-web-developers-still-use-meta-keywords-and-meta-description-tags

Comment: @CBroe I did have a look at that, but I guess I was hoping for some "X application uses them" that may have been easier to answer with a more specific context.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, its not much trouble. The tags are already defined. Secondly, just because google won't use the meta data exclusively doesn't mean that google or other sites can't use it. It's provided in an easy to read place for programs that need it. Parsing html can be hard, especially when your site is constantly changing, so providing a constant place for tags with little to no effort is just something that they do.

Comment: Well, I'm curious, really. What DOES use meta keywords?